# Hormiga and hormigón: How are they related?

Tags: etimología

**Hormiga** is the Spanish for *ant* and **hormigón** for *concrete*. Now ants and concrete hardly seem to have anything in common between them. However, I read [somewhere](http://www.myetymology.com/spanish/hormig%C3%B3n.html) that **hormigón** was derived from **hormigo** which itself came from **hormiga**. How is that possible? Is this the correct etymology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking that reference, I can tell you that I'm quite sure that **hormiga** does come from **formica**.

It seems that the roots of **hormigón** are unclear. Check [this document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmaterconstrucc.revistas.csic.es%2Findex.php%2Fmaterconstrucc%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F961%2F1017&ei=xpstVM3rGdSryASV34GIAw&usg=AFQjCNF2YA0Ws-kZc7-KBigafNMx91BWgg&sig2=Q4PiT5Tg5r11ebw2Q6MDcw) to learn more about some of the possibilities. Theories are:

- HORMIGÓN deriva de FORMICARE, contruir con tapial
- La sustitución de la F inicial por H y subsiguiente pérdida es un fenómeno primitivo debido a la influencia ibérica de los dialectos vecinos al vasco
- Otra hipótesis relaciona HORMIGÓN con HORMIGOS "gachas", comida hecha con trigo o 
  maíz quebrantados o pan desmenuzado, cocidos con agua o leche

[Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hormig%C3%B3n#Etimolog.C3.ADa) says this about the etymology of hormigón:

> «Hormigón» procede del término formicō (o formáceo), palabra latina que alude a la cualidad de «moldeable» o «dar forma». El término concreto, definido en el diccionario de la RAE como americanismo, también es originario del latín: procede de la palabra concretus, que significa «crecer unidos», o «unir». Concretus es una palabra compuesta en la su prefijo es com- (unión) y el participio pasado del verbo crĕscere (crecer). Su uso en idioma español se transmite por vía de la cultura anglosajona,2 como anglicismo (o calco semántico), siendo la voz inglesa original concrete. Etimológicamente concreto es sinónimo de concrecionado y concreción que es la unión de diversas partículas para formar una masa.